# Heritrix: Ignoring robots.txt for one site only

Tags: heritrix

I am using Heritrix 3.2.0.

I want to grab everything from one site, including pages normally protected by robots.txt.

However, I do *not* want to ignore robots.txt for *other* sites. (Don't want Facebook or Google to get angry with us, you know)

I have tried to set up a sheet overlay, closely resembling the one in the 3.0/3.1 manual (At the end of the post)

The job builds without comments, but the overlay doesn't seem to be triggered, the local robots.txt is still obeyed.

So, what am I doing wrong?

Stig Hemmer

```
<beans>
  ... all the normal default crawler-beans.cxml stuff ...

  <bean id="sheetOverLayManager" autowire="byType"
        class="org.archive.crawler.spring.SheetOverlaysManager">
  </bean>

  <bean class='org.archive.crawler.spring.SurtPrefixesSheetAssociation'>
    <property name='surtPrefixes'>
     <list>
       <value>
http://(no,kommune,trondheim,)/
https://(no,kommune,trondheim,)/
       </value>
     </list>
   </property>
   <property name='targetSheetNames'>
     <list>
       <value>noRobots</value>
     </list>
   </property>
 </bean>

 <bean id='noRobots' class='org.archive.spring.Sheet'>
   <property name='map'>
     <map>
       <entry key='metadata.robotsPolicyName' value='ignore'/>
     </map>
   </property>
 </bean>
</beans>
```

Answer (score 2):

Original Poster here.  As always, Problem Exists Between Keyboard And Chair.

It turns out I didn't understand how SURTs work.

New and improved configuration:

```
<property name='surtPrefixes'>
  <list>
    <value>http://(no,kommune,trondheim,</value>
    <value>https://(no,kommune,trondheim,</value>
  </list>
</property>
```

The important change was leaving the end of each SURT open since I actually wanted to include subsites in the rules.

I also split the two SURTs into two `<value>`s.  Not sure if that was necessary, but at least it is more readable.

I still have problems, but at least I have *new* problems!

Comment: Oh, sure, you have to put one surt per value tag. I didn't see that in your original post. You were actually referring to one weird "surt" made of two surts with a carriage return in between that wouldn't match anything.

Comment: I fixed the value tags first, but that didn't help.  Then I fixed the open-endedness and that worked.  So I was sure the open-endedness was a problem, but I didn't know if the double value was imporant. (And too lazy to check) Thank you for telling me.